# Why does it give me an error onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So here is my code for what I have so far in my extension. I want to make a game where you click on the dot when it shows up. The problem is no matter what I do I seem to get an error when I click the button.

popup.js

```
     //The Dot 
        (function makeDiv(){
            // vary size for fun
            var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 20).toFixed();
            var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
            $newdiv = $('<button type="button" id="button" style=" border-radius: 500px;outline: none;padding: 0;border: none;"></button>').css({
                'width':divsize+'px',
                'height':divsize+'px',
                'background-color': color
            });

            // make position sensitive to size and document's width
            var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
            var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

            $newdiv.css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px',
                'display':'none'
            }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function(){
              $(this).remove();
              makeDiv(); 
            }); 
        })();

        //Score
          window.onload = function() {
            var a =0;
            function

 myFunction()
        {
            a= a +1;
            document.getElementById('demo').textContent=a;
        }
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = myFunction;
    }
```

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="background.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

 <style>

 #score{
 position:absolute:
 margin:auto;
 left:0px;right:0px;top:40px;
 width:100%;height:10px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:160%;
 }

</style>

 </head>

 <body style="width:400px;height:500px;">
 <script src="popup.js"></script>

 <div id="score">
 <p>Score:</p>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <div>
 </body>

</html>
```

I know it is most likely a stupid error, but I can not seem to figure it out. The score will count for the first button but not the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your main problem was that when you were creating a new element, in this case $newdiv, you weren't reassigning your onclick on creation. The first one worked because you were assigning it for that first time then every circle after that had no onclick, and therefore did nothing when clicked.

To fix it I had to restructure your code a bit so that we could use myFunction inside of the makeDiv function to be able to assign it each time we create a new circle.

```js
(function() {
 //Score
 var a = 0;
 
 function myFunction() {
  a = a + 1;
  $("#demo").text(a);
 }
  
 //The Dot 
 function makeDiv() {
  // vary size for fun
  var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 20).toFixed();
  var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
  $newdiv = $('<button type="button" id="button" style=" border-radius: 500px;outline: none;padding: 0;border: none;"></button>').css({
   'width':divsize+'px',
   'height':divsize+'px',
   'background-color': color
  });

  // make position sensitive to size and document's width
  var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
  var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

  $newdiv.css({
   'position':'absolute',
   'left':posx+'px',
   'top':posy+'px',
   'display':'none'
  }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).remove();
   makeDiv();
  }); 
  
  // Assign MyFunction as onclick each time we make a new circle.
  $newdiv.on("click", myFunction);
 }
 
 makeDiv(); // Make our initial circle
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="background.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

 <style>

 #score{
 position:absolute:
 margin:auto;
 left:0px;right:0px;top:40px;
 width:100%;height:10px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:160%;
 }

</style>

 </head>

 <body style="width:400px;height:500px;">
 <script src="popup.js"></script>

 <div id="score">
 <p>Score:</p>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <div>
 </body>

</html>
```